# Safe cancelling of CopyFileEx process

Tags: c++, winapi

I've created a dialogbox with progress bar and a cancel button using CreateDialogParam to show status while copying several files (using CopyFileEx).

How do I cancel the process using CopyFileEx correctly, starting from pressing the cancel button in dialogbox? Is there anyway I can do it without using global variable? And How do I correctly handle the returned PROGRESS_CANCEL? I have provided questions in the code below to make clearer what help do I need.

```
//copy function
BOOL copy(HWND &hWnd, std::vector <FILECONSOLIDATEPARAMS> &vec)
{
    //pass vector as lparam to dialogbox proc
    LPARAM lp = reinterpret_cast<LPARAM>(&vec);

    HWND hCopy = CreateDialogParam(GetModuleHandle(NULL), 
        MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDD_DIALOG1),
        hwndmain, (DLGPROC)dlgboxcopyproc, lp);

    static HWND hIDC_STATIC, hIDC_STATIC4;
        hIDC_STATIC = GetDlgItem(hCopy, IDC_STATIC);
        hIDC_STATIC4 = GetDlgItem(hCopy, IDC_STATIC4);
        LPBOOL pbCancel = FALSE;

    size_t s;
    for (s = 0; s != vec.size(); s++)
    {
        SendMessage(hIDC_STATIC, WM_SETTEXT, 0, (LPARAM)vec[s].filename);
        SendMessage(hIDC_STATIC4, WM_SETTEXT, 0,(LPARAM)vec[s].destination);

        BOOL b = CopyFileEx(vec[s].filename, vec[s].destination,
            &CopyProgressRoutine,(LPVOID)hCopy,pbCancel, NULL);

        //how to catch and process PROGRESS_CANCEL?

        if (!b)
        {
            DWORD dw = GetLastError();
            ShowErrMsg(dw);
        }
}

    PostMessage(hCopy, WM_DESTROY, 0, 0);

    return TRUE;
}


//dialogbox procedure
INT_PTR CALLBACK dlgboxcopyproc(HWND hWndDlg,UINT Msg,WPARAM wParam,LPARAM 
    lParam)
{
    //translate passed lparam back to vector
    std::vector<FILECONSOLIDATEPARAMS>& vect = 
    *reinterpret_cast<std::vector<FILECONSOLIDATEPARAMS>*>(lParam);

    INITCOMMONCONTROLSEX _icex;
    _icex.dwSize = sizeof(INITCOMMONCONTROLSEX);
    _icex.dwICC = ICC_PROGRESS_CLASS;
    InitCommonControlsEx(&_icex);

    static HWND hParent;
    static HWND hIDCancel;
    static HWND hIDC_PROGRESS1;
    static HWND hIDC_STATIC;

    hParent = GetParent(hWndDlg);
    hIDCancel = GetDlgItem(hWndDlg, IDCANCEL);
    hIDC_PROGRESS1 = GetDlgItem(hWndDlg, IDC_PROGRESS1);

    switch (Msg)
    {
        case WM_INITDIALOG:
        {
            SendMessage(hIDC_PROGRESS1, PBM_SETRANGE, 0, MAKELPARAM(0, 100));
        }
        return (INT_PTR)TRUE;

        case WM_COMMAND:
        {
            switch (LOWORD(wParam))
            {
                case IDCANCEL:
                EndDialog(hWndDlg, FALSE); //how to make pbCancel = TRUE?
                return (INT_PTR)TRUE;
            }
        }
        break;

        case WM_DESTROY:
        {
            DestroyWindow(hWndDlg);
        }
    }
    return FALSE;
}

//copyprogressroutine callback function
DWORD CALLBACK CopyProgressRoutine(LARGE_INTEGER TotalFileSize, 
    LARGE_INTEGER TotalBytesTransferred, LARGE_INTEGER StreamSize, 
    LARGE_INTEGER StreamBytesTransferred, DWORD dwStreamNumber, DWORD 
    dwCallbackReason, HANDLE hSourceFile, HANDLE hDestinationFile, LPVOID 
    lpData)
{   
    HWND hWndDlg = (HWND)lpData;

    static HWND hwndIDC_PROGRESS1;
    hwndIDC_PROGRESS1 = GetDlgItem(hWndDlg, IDC_PROGRESS1);

    DOUBLE Percentage = ((DOUBLE)TotalBytesTransferred.QuadPart / 
        (DOUBLE)TotalFileSize.QuadPart) * 100;

    switch (dwCallbackReason)
    {
        case CALLBACK_CHUNK_FINISHED:
        SendMessage(hwndIDC_PROGRESS1, PBM_SETPOS, (WPARAM) Percentage, 0);
        break;

        case CALLBACK_STREAM_SWITCH:
        Percentage = 0;
        break;
    }
    return PROGRESS_CONTINUE; //how to make conditional return PROGRESS_CANCEL?
}
```

Comment: Use custom windows messages. Look up ``WM_USER`` then you can post cancel message using ``PostMessage`` API and handle it in your window procedure

Comment: The *lpData* parameter to [CopyFileEx](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363852.aspx) can be used to provide user-defined context. Simply pass a pointer to a custom structure, that - among other information - contains a member to control cancellation. @Asesh: Messages in the `WM_USER` range are meant to be used by the window class implementation. Unless you registered the window class, use messages in the `WM_APP` range instead.

Comment: `LPBOOL pbCancel = FALSE;` and `CopyFileEx(..pbCancel)` say that you not understand in/out params at all

Comment: you need use `BOOL bCancel = FALSE` instead, and pass `&bCancel` to `CopyFileEx`, and associate with dialog some c++ class and `BOOL bCancel` must be member of this class, and when user press button - you simply set it to true - `bCancel = TRUE`

Comment: *How do I correctly handle the returned `PROGRESS_CANCEL`* - you not need handle it. you can return `PROGRESS_CANCEL` - and handle it will be system, not you

Comment: also `EndDialog` have sense only dialog boxes created by the `DialogBox`, `DialogBoxParam`, `DialogBoxIndirect`, and `DialogBoxIndirectParam` functions . for `CreateDialogParam` use it is error- it not destroy dialog

Comment: Also, the way to destroy a window is `DestroyWindow`, not `PostMessage(WM_DESTROY)`.

Comment: and you need call `CopyFileEx` in separate thread - not from gui thread

Answer (score 0):

code like

```
LPBOOL pbCancel = FALSE;
CopyFileEx(, pbCancel, )
```

senseless. really we simply pass 0 in place *pbCancel* and have no ability cancel operation.
we need **alocate** some variable (let name it *bCancel*) of type BOOL and pass pointer of this variable to `CopyFileEx`
something like this:

```
BOOL bCancel = FALSE;
CopyFileEx(, &bCancel, )
```

the `CopyFileEx` will be periodically query value of this variable by passed pointer and if it became true - break operation and return `ERROR_REQUEST_ABORTED` error.

the next - `CopyFileEx` not return until operation is complete - this is **synchronous api** - as result it can not be called from GUI thread (or it simply block GUI). need call it from separate thread.

so basic solution - allocate some data structure, here place `BOOL bCancel`, and other data, which we will be use during copy. we will access this data structure from 2 threads - gui thread (from dialog procedure) and from separate thread, which will call `CopyFileEx`. for correct implement this - need use reference counting on structure. the *lpProgressRoutine* need post messages to gui thread for notify it about progress (gui thread can move progress bars on this notification). dialog can containing for example `Cancel` button. when user click it - GUI thread simply set `bCancel = TRUE`, as result `CopyFileEx` abort operation on next chunk. for start copy - need start new thread, which call `CopyFileEx`. based on required logic - can do this from `WM_INITDIALOG` or say when user press some button in dialog

basic code:

```
struct CopyDlg 
{
    enum {
        WM_COPYRESULT = WM_APP, WM_PROGRESS
    };

    struct ProgressData {
        LARGE_INTEGER TotalFileSize;
        LARGE_INTEGER TotalBytesTransferred;
        LARGE_INTEGER StreamSize;
        LARGE_INTEGER StreamBytesTransferred;
        DWORD dwStreamNumber;
    };

    PCWSTR m_lpExistingFileName, m_lpNewFileName;
    HWND m_hwnd, m_hwndFile, m_hwndStream;
    ULONG m_shift;
    LONG m_dwRefCount;
    LONG m_hwndLock;
    BOOL m_bCancel;

    CopyDlg()
    {
        m_dwRefCount = 1;
    }

    void AddRef()
    {
        InterlockedIncrement(&m_dwRefCount);
    }

    void Release()
    {
        if (!InterlockedDecrement(&m_dwRefCount))
        {
            delete this;
        }
    }

    void LockWnd()
    {
        InterlockedIncrement(&m_hwndLock);
    }

    void UnlockWnd()
    {
        if (!InterlockedDecrement(&m_hwndLock))
        {
            // want m_hwnd be valid at PostMessage(p->m_hwnd,) time
            EndDialog(m_hwnd, 0);
        }
    }

    void OnProgress(DWORD dwCallbackReason, ProgressData* p)
    {
        if (dwCallbackReason == CALLBACK_STREAM_SWITCH)
        {
            if (p->dwStreamNumber == 1)
            {
                m_shift = 0;

                LONGLONG QuadPart = p->TotalFileSize.QuadPart;

                while (QuadPart > MAXLONG)
                {
                    m_shift++;
                    QuadPart >>= 1;
                }

                SendMessage(m_hwndFile, PBM_SETRANGE32, 0, (LPARAM)QuadPart);
                SendMessage(m_hwndFile, PBM_SETPOS, 0, 0);
            }

            SendMessage(m_hwndStream, PBM_SETRANGE32, 0, (LPARAM)(p->StreamSize.QuadPart >> m_shift));
            SendMessage(m_hwndStream, PBM_SETPOS, 0, 0);
        }
        else
        {
            SendMessage(m_hwndStream, PBM_SETPOS, (LPARAM)(p->StreamBytesTransferred.QuadPart >> m_shift), 0);
            SendMessage(m_hwndFile, PBM_SETPOS, (LPARAM)(p->TotalBytesTransferred.QuadPart >> m_shift), 0);
        }
    }

    ULONG StartCopy(PCWSTR lpExistingFileName, PCWSTR lpNewFileName)
    {
        m_bCancel = FALSE;
        m_lpExistingFileName = lpExistingFileName; 
        m_lpNewFileName = lpNewFileName;

        LockWnd();
        AddRef();
        if (HANDLE hThread = CreateThread(0, 0, reinterpret_cast<PTHREAD_START_ROUTINE>(CopyThread), this, 0, 0))
        {
            CloseHandle(hThread);
            return NOERROR;
        }

        Release();
        UnlockWnd();
        return GetLastError();
    }

    static INT_PTR CALLBACK _DialogProc(HWND hwndDlg, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
    {
        if (uMsg == WM_INITDIALOG)
        {
            SetWindowLongPtr(hwndDlg, DWLP_USER, (LONG_PTR)lParam);
        }

        if (CopyDlg* p = reinterpret_cast<CopyDlg*>(GetWindowLongPtrW(hwndDlg, DWLP_USER)))
        {
            p->AddRef();
            INT_PTR r = p->DialogProc(hwndDlg, uMsg, wParam, lParam);
            p->Release();
            return r;
        }

        return 0;
    }

    INT_PTR DialogProc(HWND hwndDlg, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
    {
        switch (uMsg)
        {
        case WM_NCDESTROY:
            Release();
            break;

        case WM_DESTROY:
            m_bCancel = TRUE;
            break;

        case WM_COMMAND:
            switch (wParam)
            {
            case MAKEWPARAM(IDCANCEL, BN_CLICKED):
                m_bCancel = TRUE;
                break;
            }
            break;

        case WM_CLOSE:
            m_bCancel = TRUE;
            UnlockWnd();
            ShowWindow(hwndDlg, SW_HIDE);//for not get wm_close twice
            break;

        case WM_COPYRESULT:
            UnlockWnd();
            // lParam == error code from CopyFileExW
            DbgPrint("CopyFileExW=%u\n", (ULONG)lParam);
            break;

        case WM_PROGRESS:
            OnProgress((DWORD)wParam, reinterpret_cast<ProgressData*>(lParam));
            delete (void*)lParam;
            break;

        case WM_INITDIALOG:
            AddRef();
            m_hwnd = hwndDlg;
            m_hwndStream = GetDlgItem(hwndDlg, IDC_PROGRESS1);
            m_hwndFile = GetDlgItem(hwndDlg, IDC_PROGRESS2);
            m_hwndLock = 1;
            StartCopy(L"**", L"**");
            break;
        }
        return 0;
    }

    static ULONG CALLBACK CopyThread(CopyDlg* p)
    {
        PostMessage(p->m_hwnd, WM_COPYRESULT, 0, CopyFileExW(
            p->m_lpExistingFileName, p->m_lpNewFileName, 
            reinterpret_cast<LPPROGRESS_ROUTINE>(CopyProgressRoutine), 
            p, &p->m_bCancel, 0) ? NOERROR : GetLastError());

        p->Release();

        return 0;
    }

    static DWORD CALLBACK CopyProgressRoutine(
        __in      LARGE_INTEGER TotalFileSize,
        __in      LARGE_INTEGER TotalBytesTransferred,
        __in      LARGE_INTEGER StreamSize,
        __in      LARGE_INTEGER StreamBytesTransferred,
        __in      DWORD dwStreamNumber,
        __in      DWORD dwCallbackReason,
        __in      HANDLE /*hSourceFile*/,
        __in      HANDLE /*hDestinationFile*/,
        __in_opt  CopyDlg* p
        )
    {
        switch(dwCallbackReason)
        {
        case CALLBACK_CHUNK_FINISHED:
        case CALLBACK_STREAM_SWITCH:

            if (ProgressData* data = new ProgressData)
            {
                data->TotalFileSize = TotalFileSize;
                data->TotalBytesTransferred = TotalBytesTransferred;
                data->StreamSize = StreamSize;
                data->StreamBytesTransferred = StreamBytesTransferred;
                data->dwStreamNumber = dwStreamNumber;

                if (!PostMessage(p->m_hwnd, WM_PROGRESS, dwCallbackReason, (LPARAM)data))
                {
                    delete data;
                    return PROGRESS_CANCEL;
                }
            }
            break;
        }

        // for debugging
        //Sleep(3000);
        //MessageBoxW(0,0,0,0);
        return PROGRESS_CONTINUE;
    }
};

if (CopyDlg* p = new CopyDlg)
{
    DialogBoxParamW((HINSTANCE)&__ImageBase, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDD_DIALOG1), HWND_DESKTOP, CopyDlg::_DialogProc, (LPARAM)p);
    p->Release();
}
```

Comment: Could you reword your answer, leaving out personal attacks?

Comment: Thread A calls `AddRef()` and gets preempted, just before it executes `InterlockedIncrement`. Now thread B calls `Release()`, running to completion, calling `InterlockedDecrement` and deleting the instance. Next up is thread A, poking a hole into random memory. Not much fun debugging.

Comment: @IInspectable - you mistake  - every thread have it own, independed reference count. every thread release **self** reference. if you note - before start thread B - i call `AddRef()` **before** call `CreateThread` - so give reference to thread B. it call `Release` in the end of it execution, when no more access shared data (`CopyDlg`) or i call `Release` from thread A if create B failed. no mistake in my code here

Comment: Your usage may not expose the bug. That doesn't make the code thread-safe, though. It isn't.

Comment: @IInspectable - if say i call `AddRef()` **after** `CreateThread` - this will be mistake. but in my code no. and debugging or say emulate this situation very easy - simply insert `messagebox` for example in point where thread can switch and test. insert `messagebox` in my `AddRef` how you say before it executes `InterlockedIncrement` and try create error

Comment: @IInspectable - code not became not thread safe only because you say this without any proof.

Comment: @IInspectable - the bug in thread safety very easy proof by insert `messagebox` (or suspend thread - some tools/debuggers allow this) in correct places. what you say about *AddRef() and gets preempted,..* simply is wrong and empty words. try create poc

Comment: I [explained](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48264892/safe-cancelling-of-copyfileex-process/48269015?noredirect=1#comment83525682_48269015), how the code can fail. If you cannot argue for your code, that this scenario cannot ever happen, then this is a prove. It doesn't matter how *you* use the code. The code itself isn't thread-safe. But, trying to allure you into logical reasoning is a tiresome exercise, so I'll just let it rest.

Comment: @IInspectable - no, you nothing explained. you simply mistake and can not understand or admit it.again your mistake - both threads A and B in my code - have **self** reference to object. *thread A, poking a hole into random memory* - not, because it have **self** reference, the thread B - release **self** reference and this not affected thread A.

Comment: @IInspectable - and funny that you cling to the absolutely correct code, although another non-correct moment (I did this to simplify code), which you did not notice :)

Comment: @IInspectable - however very interesting view your comments or answer here - https://stackoverflow.com/q/48272323/6401656